# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'One or more errors occurred during processing of command

Tags: wpf

```
void login()
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(" select count(*) from admin where ='"+textBox1.Text+"' and username= '"+textBox2.Text+"'",conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (textBox1.Text.Equals(" "))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ENTER USERNAME ");
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text.Equals(" "))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ENTER USERNAME ");
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                Form2 f = new Form2();
                f.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                Form2 F1 = new Form2();
                F1.Show();
                this.Hide();
                MessageBox.Show("username or password incorrect");
            }
        }
```

I want answer to this error.

Comment: You will need to put your code in a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to make it readable. Offhand, the sql query looks invalid (and in any case is subject to sql injection since it is not using parameters, just plain string concatenation).

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided has a syntax error in the SQL query. The WHERE clause is incomplete and missing a column name after the 'where =' expression. To fix this error, you need to add the column name in the WHERE clause as shown in the corrected code:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM admin WHERE column_name='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND username='" + textBox2.Text + "'", conn.
```

However, I also want to mention that your code may be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. To avoid this, you should use parameterized queries instead of concatenating user input directly into the SQL statement. The parameterized query would look like this:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM admin WHERE column_name=@value1 AND username=@value2", conn.
```

Then, you would replace @value1 and @value2 with the values of textBox1.Text and textBox2.Text using parameters, like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", textBox2.Text);
```

Note that the code samble I gave you was for MySQL. Check the documentation for your database version.